SSDT database script sets DATA_COMPRESSION per partition
When I generate database script in Visual Studio, the CREATE INDEX statement specifies DATA_COMPRESSION for each single partition:
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ExampleIndex]
    ON [dbo].[ExampleTable]([ID] ASC) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE ON PARTITIONS (1), DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE ON PARTITIONS (2), DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE ON PARTITIONS (3))
    ON [ExamplePartitionScheme] ([ID]);

This creates problems during deployment because the number of partitions in the source code is not always the same as in the database. Therefore I would like to genereta CREATE INDEX statements that defines DATA_COMPRESSION for all partitions like this in stead:
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ExampleIndex]
    ON [dbo].[ExampleTable]([ID] ASC) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
    ON [ExamplePartitionScheme] ([ID]);

I have already tried to change a bunch of the publish settings, but with no luck so far. All help is greatly appreciated!
I have tried to change various publish settings that target partitions and table options, but none of them have changed the generated statement to set DATA_COMPRESSION for all partitions.

When I generate database script by "generating script" do you mean a) importing from existing DB into sqlproj or publishing from b) existing sqlproj? If (b) then please show index definition from your source files.
